# How can I call a function once my form is loaded using Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to make an app that has a form where I show some picture. I'm trying to change this pictures when I call a function but I don't know how I can call it once the form is loaded and I want to make my loop work correctly.

.py file:

```
class TerceiroScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.name = 'tres'
        super(Screen,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        i = 0
        v.append('1.jpg')
        v.append('2.jpg')
        v.append('3.jpg')


def fc1(self):
    global i, j
    for i in range(len(v)):
        if i <= len(v):
            self.ids.image2.source = v[i]
            i = i + 1
            time.sleep(1)
        else:
            i = 0
            self.ids.image2.source = v[i]
```

and my .kv:

```
<TerceiroScreen>:
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'logo.jpg'


StackLayout:
    orientation: 'tb-lr'
    Image:
        source: '0.jpg'
        size_hint:(.4,.4)
        id: image2

    GridLayout:
        cols: 1
        size_hint: (.1,.1)
        Button:
            text: 'function'
            font_size: '15dp'
            on_press: root.fc1()
```

I hope I have been clear, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First: Don't use globals in such a way, because it's nonsense. You define `i` in `__init__`, then define it again in `for`, which makes `global i` absolutely unnecessary. I don't see `j` anywhere, so either this is badly truncated snippet, or another unnecessary use of `global`. Use `self.i` if you want to access that inside of your class, which you can, because your function already has `self` and I think that the function is only misaligned in your question/code.

Second: As a top layer in `kv` there is always a `rule`/`class`/root widget(not really stable name even if written in docs, hehe). As a top layer I mean this:

```
<Rule>:
    Button:
<AnotherRule>:
    ...
```

that are basically python classes i.e. your `Screen`, which is a good beginning, but the `StackLayout` is already used as in python `class.add_widget()`. And you don't have anything above `StackLayout`, so this I see as a problem, because of this line: `on_press: root.fc1()`. This line is saying "look in the rule, which is python class and call its function `fc1`. No rule, no `root.something` in your way, because even if it worked(didn't test it), it'd only call `StackLayout.fc1()`, which doesn't exist.

Finally: As I see it, it may be only misaligned code. If not, you have an answer how to use kivy properly too.

```
class TerceiroScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        ...
    def fc1(self):
        ...

<TerceiroScreen>:
    canvas.before:
    StackLayout:
        GridLayout:
            Button:
                on_press: root.fc1()
```

Comment: So, I am newbie in kivy as you see, but many "bugs"  that you call I just forget to delete, like "j". But, yes, I am having many problems StackLayout, this  code I paste here is just a draft of my work. I would like to know how I can call some function once the form is loaded. I am very grateful for your help. I think I should test my loop in python without interface.

Comment: Just use as a rule some class from your python code(not StackLayout i.e. default kivy widget itself) e.g. `class Test(StackLayout):` which will have `fc1()` and you'll call it then with `on_press: root.fc1()`. It's explained in the [docs](https://kivy.org/docs/guide/lang.html).